# Magento 2 x Amasty override less_to_css.xml

Tags: magento2.4, less-css, amasty

I'm using my own compiler on my theme for less. I succesfully add the Amasty less files in my theme to override Amasty's default theme. However, Amasty is using a custom compiler (cssOptions) to generate a CSS and include it in the header.

I tried it with several approaches.

- Override etc/less_to_css.xml

Original

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:amasty:module:Amasty_Base:etc/less_to_css.xsd">
    <module name="Amasty_CheckoutCore">
        <handle name="checkout_index_index" />
        <cssOptions fileName="amcheckout" path="css/source/mkcss" />
        <ifconfig>amasty_checkout/general/enabled</ifconfig>
    </module>
</config>
```

Edited

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:amasty:module:Amasty_Base:etc/less_to_css.xsd">
    <module name="Amasty_CheckoutCore">
        <handle name="checkout_index_index" />
        <ifconfig>amasty_checkout/general/enabled</ifconfig>
    </module>
</config>
```

But that doesn't work (fairly logical I pressume). I tried it with copying over the file

```
app/design/Theme/base/Amasty_CheckoutCore/styles/mkcss/amcheckout.less
```

This is the file

```
ing css file. Path from vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank
@import (reference) '../../../lib::css/source/lib/_lib.less'; // Library files
@import (reference) '../../../lib::css/source/lib/_responsive.less'; // Global responsive
@import '../_module.less';
```

Tried to remove it's content..but it's just not deleting the content or the reference to the files. The other .less files ARE compiling in my own compiler, so I know everything should be in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to remove css files which are generating from `etc/less_to_css.xml` then we need to override that file by creating module. Please following below steps:-

1] create app/code/Trek/Amastyoverride/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Trek_Amastyoverride',
    __DIR__
);
```

2] create app/code/Trek/Amastyoverride/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Trek_Amastyoverride" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Amasty_CheckoutCore" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

3] create app/code/Trek/Amastyoverride/etc/less_to_css.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:amasty:module:Amasty_Base:etc/less_to_css.xsd">
    <module name="Amasty_CheckoutCore">
        <handle name="" />
        <cssOptions fileName="amcheckout" path="css/source/mkcss" />
        <ifconfig>amasty_checkout/general/enabled</ifconfig>
    </module>
</config>
```

In above `less_to_css.xml` if we want to remove calling amcheckout.less file from whole website then we just need to empty handle name like `<handle name="" />` . Css files are calling based on declared handle. Here in your shared file handle is `checkout_index_index` so css file only call on checkout page. So if you want to remove css file from calling then just empty handle.

If you want to call that css files in other pages then just add multiple handles like following way:-

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:amasty:module:Amasty_Base:etc/less_to_css.xsd">
    <module name="Amasty_CheckoutCore">
        <handle name="checkout_cart_index" />
        <handle name="catalog_product_view" />
        <cssOptions fileName="amcheckout" path="css/source/mkcss" />
        <ifconfig>amasty_checkout/general/enabled</ifconfig>
    </module>
</config>
```

I hope it works. Thanks in advance.